# Gitblit hook that parses changed files

Tags: git, groovy, jgit, gitblit

How can I have access to the changed files in a gitblit hook? When I do a push, I need to get the list of all the files that were changed and do some tests on them, how can I achieve this?

I did the following:

```
RevWalk rw = new RevWalk(repository);
ObjectId head = repository.resolve(Constants.HEAD);
RevCommit commit = rw.parseCommit(head);
RevCommit parent = rw.parseCommit(commit.getParent(0).getId());
DiffFormatter df = new DiffFormatter(DisabledOutputStream.INSTANCE);
df.setRepository(repository);
df.setDiffComparator(RawTextComparator.DEFAULT);
df.setDetectRenames(true);
List<DiffEntry> diffs = df.scan(parent.getTree(), commit.getTree());
for (DiffEntry diff : diffs) {
    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("({0} {1} {2}", diff.getChangeType().name(), diff.getNewMode().getBits(), diff.getNewPath()));
}
```

What can I do next to get the actual file contents of a DiffEntry?

Comment: To clarify your question. Do you want the diff between the two versions (i.e. what  `df.format()` prints) or the entire content of the old and the new version?

Comment: I just want to get the content of the new version, full content and also a way to see the change that was made. Thanks.

Comment: The new version can be obtained through the `ObjectLoader` returned by `repository.open( head )`. Are you aware that `df.format(DiffEntry)` prints out the changes in diff format?

Comment: df.format(DiffEntry) prints out and empty String for me

Comment: Note that `DiffFormatter` writes to the `OutputStream` passed to the constructor.

Comment: Can you please give more concrete code examples regarding the ObjectLoader? I am not familiarized with the JGit API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97990/discussion-between-patentul-and-rudiger-herrmann).